# How to validate multiple Tables before inserting on sink table in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have several sets of Tables let's say employee, dept, account, etc. with the schema as follows

```
Employee ->empId, Name
dept->deptid,empId, deptName
account->empId,accID, name
```

so before inserting a new record on the table **dept** I have to validate if the empID is present on the **Employee** and **account** table or not.

Is there an option in Azure Datafactory to validate these condition before inserting on **Dept** table being **dept** as my sink table?

Answer (score 1):

I used a copy data pipeline to achieve this. I created a table of values to be inserted into `dept` table called `dept2` with same schema. Using copy data activity, the requirement is to filter and insert records where the new 'empId' records exist in both `employee` and `account` table. So, select source table as `dept2` and select 'Use Query' method.

[image]

Write a desired query in the Query text area provided. As specified, using the query given below would give only the records from dept2 (table values to be inserted) whose empId exists in both ‘employee’ and ‘account’ table.

```
select d2.deptid, d2.empId, d2.deptName from [dbo].[dept2] as d2 
where d2.empId in(select empid from [dbo].[employee]) 
and d2.empId in(select empId from [dbo].[account])
```

When you preview the data, you can see that the query is executed and only the records where 'empId' exists in both `employee` and `account` are visible. Now in the sink tab, create a linked service directing to `dept` table.

We can execute the pipeline now and it successfully accomplishes the task of validating the records to be inserted such that the new 'empId' pre-exists in both the other tables. The following are the images of sample data with tables.

employee table:

[image]

account table:

[image]

dept2 table (insert values):

[image]

Output:

[image]

So, you can filter or validate the data using this query tab and copy only required data to your destination table.

Comment: So basically there is no Direct way to validate (running the SQLs), we need some kind of staging in between in this case its dept2 table

Comment: We can run SQL queries even with pre-copy scripts and post-copy scripts in dataflows or pipelines where the sink is an SQL table. Using the pre-copy scripts to validate in this case is much more complex than the provided solution. But there has to be a source which in this case was dept2 table.

Comment: There is another way to execute an SQL query in Azure data factory. There is an activity called 'Script' in ADF pipeline. Create a linked service to your database and you can write an SQL script. Create a stored procedure to insert based on condition (if empid exists in both `employee` and `account` tables) in your database. When you run the pipeline using exec stored procedure query, it executes the stored procedure and inserts based on condition. Using this, you can only validate for one row, where you enter the values manually in the Script activity manually.